# How to set the camera distortion by script?

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, camera, numpy

**I have:**

1. A 3D point cloud indoor scene;
2. camera_poses.npy: records the camera pose changes, e.g. (x,y,z,qx,qy,qz,qw)
3. camera_info.txt: stores the parameters of the real camera, the contents are as follows:

```
height: 480
width: 640
distortion_model: "plumb_bob"
D: [-0.05551552399992943, 0.06454764306545258, 0.00030259598861448467, 0.00033357078791595995, -0.020629441365599632]
K: [383.1800842285156, 0.0, 316.1011962890625, 0.0, 382.9574279785156, 241.73776245117188, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
R: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
P: [383.1800842285156, 0.0, 316.1011962890625, 0.0, 0.0, 382.9574279785156, 241.73776245117188, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
```

> D: The distortion parameters, size depending on the distortion model.
> For "plumb_bob", the 5 parameters are: (k1, k2, t1, t2, k3).
>
> K: Intrinsic camera matrix for the raw (distorted) images
>
> R: Rectification matrix (stereo cameras only). A rotation matrix aligning the camera coordinate system to the ideal stereo image plane so that epipolar lines in both stereo images are parallel.
>
> P: Projection/camera matrix

More details about the D K R P can be found [here](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html).

**What I have achieved:**

Makes the blender camera move through the scene based on camera pose information, rendering one image per move and outputting it.

**The problem:**

As you can see in "camera_info.txt", the real camera lens has distortion, i.e. `distortion_model: "plumb_bob"`. I want to set this distortion (mode, parameters) in Blender with a python script (with bpy) to ensure that the rendered image will have the same distortion as the real image for each move.

What should I do? I tried searching for "distortion" in the Blender Python API, but there doesn't seem to be a function/parameter that I can use directly? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, Dongze.. welcome to BSE. I think a couple of links out to authoritative references to give your single-letter parameters meaning for the more naïve reader, would be helpful, here.

Comment: @RobinBetts Thanks for the tip, I added the relevant link.